# Watch Connectivity not working

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchconnectivity, wcsession

I am trying to create an app where I can send information from an apple watch to my ios Parent App. I have written the code for it but when I run the WatchConnectivity App, the information does not transfer between the apple watch and the parent ios app. This may be a problem with my code or it may be because for some reason the watch does not start with the app. I have to go to the simulator and click on the app to get it started. Is this why my code is not working?

**InterfaceController.m**

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>

@interface InterfaceController() <WCSessionDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) WCSession *session;

@end

@implementation InterfaceController

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
            self.session = [WCSession defaultSession];
            self.session.delegate = self;
            [self.session activateSession];
        }
    }
return self;
}


- (IBAction)catPressed {
     [self sendText:@"cat"];
}
- (IBAction)dogPressed {
     [self sendText:@"dog"];
}
- (IBAction)pandaPressed {
    [self sendText:@"panda"];
}
- (IBAction)bunnyPressed {
    [self sendText:@"bunny"];
 }

-(void)sendText:(NSString *)text {
     NSDictionary *applicationDict = @{@"emoji":text};
     [self.session updateApplicationContext:applicationDict error:nil];

}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>

@interface ViewController () <WCSessionDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
         WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
         session.delegate = self;
         [session activateSession];

         NSLog(@"HIIII");
     }
 }

 - (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext {

    NSString *text = [applicationContext objectForKey:@"text"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text: %@", text]];
    });
}
```

Comment: I experienced this too, I needed to open the parent app on the iPhone first to start sharing information between the iPhone and Watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to open the parent app on the iPhone first to start sharing information between the iPhone and Watch. Thanks to MSU_Bulldog for suggesting this idea.